# Crystal Reports: Displaying a record if another record is null, and vice versa

Tags: crystal-reports, null, report, field, subreports

I am building a subreport and have two tables from which I am using one field each containing a phone number.

Original Number {TABLE1.ORG}

Temporary Number {TABLE2.TEM}

**What I want:**

If {TABLE2.TEM} is not null, then hide {TABLE1.ORG}, else show {TABLE1.ORG}

I tried to use the above as a formula but it doesn't work too Since these both fields are from two different tables if place them **next to each other** (without any formulas or suppression) in the design mode:

**{TABLE1.ORG}**    **{TABLE2.TEM}**

...I see them on different lines in preview mode:

```
                 +971 4 321321321

+971 4 123123123
```

Maybe because the formula reads records and evaluate from the same line, I guess this is the reason why above is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious why the two fields are appearing on different lines in preview mode, but it's unlikely to be because they are from different tables - it's more likely to be because there isn't enough room in the layout for them both to display in one line, and so they are growing to a size that canb be displayed.

To conditionally suppress {TABLE1.ORG} based on whether the other field is not null:

- right-click on {TABLE1.ORG} and select Format Field...
- in the Common tab within the Format Editor dialog, click on the conditional suppress formula button `x-2` and enter the formula `not IsNull ({TABLE2.TEM})` in the Format Formula Editor.
- click Save and close to exit from the Format Formula Editor, then click OK to exit the Format Editor dialog.

If you now preview the report, you should find that {TABLE1.ORG} is suppressed where {TABLE2.TEM} is not null.

Note that if you make display of **both** fields conditional on whether the other is null, then **both** will be suppressed where neither is null.

Comment: Hi @Mark-bannister , Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid this did not work out. The reason I understand is that these two values are from two different tables which have values pushed into them from a **master event table** These two tables are linked with the Master table only, and are not linked with eachother. I do not have access to make changes to the database therefore will have to see if I can run SQL queries through Crystal Report it self. BTW I am using Ver. 11

Comment: @user1134459: Your comment is unclear - perhaps you can expand your question to include which tables are being accessed and how? If you are already including values from both tables in the same report (and not through subreports) then this can only be because all three tables (TABLE1, TABLE2 and the Master table) are already linked together in the report.